# Finding an isomorphism between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find an isomorphism between $T: \mathbb{F_3}[x]/(x^2+x+2) \to \mathbb{F_3}[x]/ (x^2 + 1)$. We have that both of these are fields. The answer states the map $T$ is given by $T(a+bx) = (a+b) + bx$ so $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Could someone explain how they got this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanical way to find isomorphisms like this. We know that such an isomorphism exists by the uniqueness of finite fields of a given order. Furthermore, such an isomorphism is completely determined by the image of $x$. Finally, we know that the image of $x$ can be represented by $a + bx$ such that $(a + bx)^2 + (a + bx) + 2 \in (x^2 + 1)$. Expanding, we get
\begin{align*}
(a + bx)^2 + (a + bx) + 2 &= (a^2 + a + 2) + (2a + 1)bx + b^2 x^2 \\
&= (a^2 + a + 2 - b^2) + (2a + 1)bx + b^2 (x^2 + 1).
\end{align*}

This gives the equations $a^2 + a + 2 - b^2 = 0$ and $(2a + 1)b = 0$. By solving for $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb F_3$ we get $a = b = 1$ or $a = 1, b = 2$.

Comment: From the first line, why can't you simply set $(a^2 + a + 2) + (2a+1)bx + b^2x^2 = 0$ i.e. so we have $a^2 + a + 2 = 0, b(2a+1) = 0, b^2 = 0$ Why did you ehave to add a $x^2+1$ term there

Comment: All we know is that $(a + bx)^2 + (a + bx) + 2 \in (x^2 + 1)$. We need a polynomial of degree one plus a multiple of $x^2 + 1$ before we can assume that coefficients are zero.

Comment: Why do we need that exactly?

Comment: Are you still here? I cna't see why you'd need that

Comment: @algebar87 This follows from the polynomial division algorithm. Each member of $\mathbb F_3[x] / (x^2 + 1)$ can be uniquely represented by a polynomial of degree at most $1$. I'm sure you've come across this idea as you study fields. What book are you following?

Comment: I've come across it, yes but specifically, why do we need a $x^2+1$ term?

Comment: Sorry, I've literally been staring at it and I don't see it :(

Answer (score 0):

The additive rings are both vector spaces over the prime field, hence a ring isomorphism must be a vector space isomorphsm as well, which can be represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix. Also, the prime field must be left as is, hence the left columnt must be 1 0. Remains to "guess" the right column. But observe how $T$ has to act on $x^2+x+2$.

Comment: How did he get $T(a+bx) = (a+b) + bx$? Is there any way to represent this map without matrices?

Comment: How do you want it represented? It's the unique map which sends $x$ to $x+1$. This is well-defined, because $(x+1)^2 + (x+1) + 2 = x^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb F_3$.